# Go Templates: range over string

Tags: string, templates, go, range

Is there any way to range over a string in Go templates (that is, from the code in the template itself, not from native Go)? It doesn't seem to be supported directly (`The value of the pipeline must be an array, slice, map, or channel.`), but is there some hack like splitting the string into an array of single-character strings or something?

Note that I am unable to edit any go source: I'm working with a compiled binary here. I need to make this happen from the template code alone.

Comment: Do you mean iterate characters in string in template?

Comment: yeah, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FuncMap to split string into characters.

```
package main

import (
    "text/template"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    tmpl, err := template.New("foo").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "to_runes": func(s string) []string {
            r := []string{}
            for _, c := range []rune(s) {
                r = append(r, string(c))
            }
            return r
        },
    }).Parse(`{{range . | to_runes }}[{{.}}]{{end}}`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    err = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, "hello world")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

This should be:

```
[h][e][l][l][o][ ][w][o][r][l][d]
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - I don't have access to the Go source.

Comment: You can't do it without using FuncMap.

Comment: It's looking more and more that way, yeah. I'm hoping I can find some weird hacky workaround. I could make it work if there was a looping construct, but I think the authors intentionally made the templating system not Turing-complete so they could guarantee that rendering wouldn't infinite loop.