# Range over string or string array in Go template

Tags: go, go-templates

I am writing a Go template that uses consecutive alpha characters. As a simple example:

```
{{ range $i, $e := until 2 }}
{{ range $a := .[]string{"a", "b", "c"} }}
<p>{{ $e }}{{ $a }}. Sample Text</p>
{{ end }}
<br>
{{ end }}
```

Should yield:

```
<p>0a. Sample Text</p>
<p>0b. Sample Text</p>
<p>0c. Sample Text</p>
<br>
<p>1a. Sample Text</p>
<p>1b. Sample Text</p>
<p>1c. Sample Text</p>
<br>
```

The above code would work if go templates let you define arrays this way inside the template. I would need something similar to this, or the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173772/1854468), with the exception that I am not able to write my own functions. I am using this for another piece of software that lets me write go templates, but I cannot modify the go code itself, meaning no passing variables either.

Am I asking the impossible?

Comment: What functions are available in your template? `until` is not a function from the standard lib, maybe there are other "gems" where `until` comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the template host uses [Sprig](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig). Use the [list](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/lists.html) function from Sprig.

```
{{ range $i, $e := until 2 }}
{{ range $a := list "a" "b" "c"}}
<p>{{ $e }}{{ $a }}. Sample Text</p>
{{- end}}
<br>
{{- end}}
```

[Run an example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Gh4WSTuIk1V).

Comment: I had tried this before asking in the playground, but didn't know I needed to import the Sprig library. This works just the way I wanted, thanks!